# Injected object is initially missing property values in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

So I'm having a curious problem with injecting a service in Blazor Server in dotNET 7.

I have an application with a `ISession` object registered as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISession, Session>();
```

This session object looks as follows:

```
public class Session : ISession {
    public string Name{} = string.Empty;
    public List<bool> Properties = null!;
}
```

The user logs in and this `ISession` object has it's properties set properly. Now I navigate to a blazor page (.razor file) in which I inject this `ISession` object:

```
@code {
    [Inject] public ISession Session {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

and I place breakpoints at each of the major razor lifecycle events:

```
1. a breakpoint inside `OnInitialized()`
2. a breakpoint inside `OnParametersSet()`
3. a breakpoint inside `OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)`
```

and one breakpoint on a button handler of a button that is on that page:

To my surprise, when breaking inside of any of the lifecycle methods my `ISession` object is not yet populated with data (Name is empty string, and Properties is null), BUT it has object id of `{$1}` in all of these.

However, when I break inside of my button handler after pressing the button on the page, inside of it my `ISession` object is populated with ALL necessary data and its object id is still `{$1}`.

My question is, if my `ISession` object is injected before any of the lifecycle methods are executed, why doesn't it have all the property values that are eventually set on it?

Comment: If you have not set values in  `Session` after injecting it, probably will get the default value that you have set. And what output would you expect ?

Comment: The log-in service has this object injected, and sets all properties on it with the process of logging in. After logging in (props are set), I navigate to a different page, but initially the object is empty. Only after the entire page loads on a button handler does the object appear with data.

Comment: Have you tried `AddSingleton` instead of scope?

Comment: AddSingleton is not an option as this is an object that is unique to each logged in user. The object in the end has all necessary data, just not during any of razor pages lifecycle methods

Comment: And also have you tried `[Inject] public ISession Session {get;set;}` to `@inject  ISession Session`'

Comment: Yes, I tried both, for both the injected object has all properties but these properties appear only after all life-cycle methods have executed

Comment: Maybe you can post on how to set your values in login then your `ISession` interface because I tested in my end and it is working properly

Comment: Show us how and when you populate the object.  If it's empty during the initial page lifecycle then it's being reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue ended up being the following. After a user logs in, I save `ISession` to protected session storage. I re-hydrate this information into my `ISession` scoped service inside of a `CascadingValue` ...

As an aside, I do this because for some reason when `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` is called after a call is made to `AuthenticationStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState()` all my scoped services get re-initialized and using protected session storage saves all necessary user data.

..., and I did this in the `OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)` method of the `CascadingValue`. The reason I did not notice this before is because this time I used the `NavigationManager` to navigate to one of my pages, which apparently triggers a complete DOM tree re-draw, and hence invoked the life-cycle methods inside of this `CascadingValue`. Previously I only used `NavLinks` to navigate, and clicking on these does NOT invoke any life-cycle methods inside of the `CascadingValue`. One question answered, and another takes its place: why does using the `NavigationManager` to navigate invoke my `CascadingValue` life-cycle methods, and can it be made to function like a `NavLink` instead?

Much thanks to all.